# Flutter BottomNavigationBar and Signout problem

Tags: firebase, flutter, navigation

I am trying to make the sign out button on one of the pages, but whenever I have a button on the page BottomNavigationBarItem disappears.

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  //final Function(User) onSignOut;
  //Profile({@required this.onSignOut});
  Profile({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}
```

The problem is that I cannot write Profile({@required this.onSignOut}) and Profile({Key key}) : super(key: key) at the same time. If I use the first one, I have signout screen without any navigation bar, but if I use second one, I will have navigation bar but I cannot add onsignout. If I use both
Profile({@required this.onSignOut,Key key}):super(key: key)

This will give me error when I click the Signout button. More code is available in my github : https://github.com/bagmk/StartUp_Project/blob/master/TestFlutter/my_app/lib/pages/profile.dart

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this, it should work:

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(User) onSignOut;
 
  Profile({required Key key, required this.onSignOut}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I love you so much! have a great day!!!!!

Comment: Haha have a great one yourself and happy coding! Kindly upvote it^^